# How to get/set cookies with Prototype.js

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

Is there anyway to get and set cookies with prototype.js ?
I know how o do it with jQuery, but I want to do it with prototype.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prototype does not have any inbuilt function for cookie handling (for that matter even jQuery does not has too).

You can use this function to set cookies.

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
}
```

Use this function to get cookies.

```
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
    }
    return "";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Prototype does not have any cookie getting/setting functionality in its API. I recommend [Cookies.js](https://github.com/ScottHamper/Cookies).

Answer (score 0):

Do it the ***real*** prototype.js style:

```js
function getCookie(name)
{
  return document.cookie.split(";").map(function(a){a=a.split("=");return a[0].trim()==name?a[1]:null;}).compact().first();
}
```

Yes, I use allman/BSD style.